# How to findout which extensions are in use by the code-base in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to develop a server requirements files for an existing codebase.

To do that I need to identify which extensions I needed to run this codebase,

Since the code base too large to check one by one for each function. I am thinking of usuing extension name patter to identify which extensions are used in the code.

```
i.e 
openssl_open -> means openssl is required
mcrypt_store -> means mcrypt is required.
```

Will this work ?
Is there a better way of doing this ?

Some people suggest to use "get_loaded_extensions" but this is not the answer to the question that i ask.

Also its not possible to analysis every function manually because that will be about at least 3000+ functions in the code-base it self.

What i want to know is which extensions are in Use by the code-base, not the list of extensions that installed in the server.

Comment: [get_loaded_extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php)?

Comment: @Marc I think the question is the other way around. What extension *do* I need to load to be able to execute this code?

Comment: Ideally the developers of this app would have created a requirements file, e.g. a composer.json which lists all requirements... Sounds like you're trying to reverse engineer that?

Comment: Questions is how do i know which extensions are used by the codebase, NOT about which extensions are installed on the server..

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this: use a PHP tokeniser like [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/token_get_all) or [NikiC's PHP Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) to tokenise every source file, iterate over it to find all function calls and inspect those functions using [`ReflectionFunction::getExtension`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php). Don't forget to do the same for classes. This should be a reasonably small script which can produce an inventory of all used extensions/functions in your codebase, which will also flag which extensions you're currently missing (because those cannot be reflected upon).

This *will* miss functions called by name, like `call_user_func('mcrypt_store')`; but a) you can flag and manually inspect uses of `call_user_func` et al., and b) hopefully not all uses of an extension are coded like this.

Comment: its not possible to analysis every function manually because that will be about at least 3000+ functions in the code-base it self.

Comment: You did understand the part where I'm saying you can run a script across your codebase which can give you **a list of used extensions**!?